# Python - Discord Bot Loop Command and Send Messages in Private Messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

I am curious on how to loop this certain part of my code every 10 seconds.

And how would I make it so instead the Discord API private messages you the price on !price execution rather then normally messages it in the channel?

```
import requests
import discord
import asyncio

url = 'https://cryptohub.online/api/market/ticker/PLSR/'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()['BTC_PLSR']

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print("PULSAR 4 LIFE")
    print('------')

    price = print('Price:', data['last'])
    pulsar = float(data['last'])
    pulsarx = "{:.9f}".format(pulsar)

    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="PLSR Price: " + pulsarx))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!price'):
        url = 'https://cryptohub.online/api/market/ticker/PLSR/'
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()['BTC_PLSR']
        price = print('PLSR Price:', data['last'])
        pulsar = float(data['last'])
        pulsarx = "{:.9f}".format(pulsar)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Price of PULSAR: ' + pulsarx)
```

Comment: What part are you trying to loop?

Comment: I want to loop where it requests information from the API URL. So basically the information updates every set amount of time.

Comment: Basically spamming the user's dms every 10 seconds? o.o

Comment: Ooooh no. It displays it in the top-right under 'Playing' status. It won't spam anyone, I just want it so when they type in !price it DMs them the price rather then in public chat. I want it to loop repeatedly so that it keeps updating the price accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be using the `requests` module because it isn't asynchronous. Meaning, once you send a request, your bot will hang until the request is done. Instead, use `aiohttp`. As for the dming  user, just change the destination. As for the loop, a while loop will do.

```
import aiohttp
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()
url = 'https://cryptohub.online/api/market/ticker/PLSR/'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print("PULSAR 4 LIFE")
    print('------')

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while True:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                data = await response.json()
                data = data['BTC_PLSR']
                print('Price:', data['last'])
                pulsar = float(data['last'])
                pulsarx = "{:.9f}".format(pulsar)
                await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="PLSR Price: " + pulsarx))
                await asyncio.sleep(10) #Waits for 10 seconds


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("!price"):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                data = await response.json()
                data = data['BTC_PLSR']
                pulsar = float(data['last'])
                pulsarx = "{:.9f}".format(pulsar)
                await client.send_message(message.author, 'Price of PULSAR: ' + pulsarx)
```

Also, might I recommend you to check out `discord.ext.commands`. Its a much cleaner way of handling commands.

Comment: Dude thank you so much your a life-saver. I know I should as a programmer know how to do this on my own, but it's because of personal health related issues that I can't come to learn, but rather have to continuously re-teach myself things, which can end up in finding lack of answers. Thanks!

Comment: This site wouldn't exist if everyone knew how to do everything by themselves @BlakeXavier

Comment: <3 Much love going to you, have a great rest of your day/night!